# Special status of some physicists in France

Tags: physics, france

This is a question specific to France.

Permanent positions at the university typically are either research only or research and teaching. For the latter, positions are "*maître de conférences*" (assistant professor) and "*professeur des universités*" (full professor). In both cases, you are affiliated to one (or two) disciplinar "*sections*" listed [here](http://www.cpcnu.fr/listes-des-sections-cnu). Several are related to physics : 28, 29, 30, 60...

However, there exists other permanent positions called "*physicien*" (physicist), which belong to a different, separate "*corps*", see [here](http://www.cnap.obspm.fr).

How is that so and what is the difference ?

Comment: To answer briefly the "How is that so" part of your question, it is historical: these 'corps' where created by the king as fulfilling special duties to the crown. Amusingly for instance, the head of the Observatoire de Paris has a special status within the french republic in that if the president, the head of senate etc.. all die, eventually he/she become head of state (rank ~ 40 or so).

Answer (score 12):

This other kind of permanent position is very specific to a few fields of science such as astronomy, geology and probably a few other ones.

While usual permanent positions (such as something-professor) imply research and teaching, these positions add a new commitment : "observation service". 1/3 of the time should be dedicated to operate big equipments (telescope for example) for gathering and analysing data that will be useful to the community. For astronomy it implies missions on telescope sites for instance.